# Warning message on making evaluations in an old notebook

Tags: notebooks

I loaded a very old notebook, written in 2006 for Mathematica 4.2, in version 9. I selected "Revert to older styling".

When I execute any cell in that notebook, I get a warning message:

> Set::wrsym : Symbol DefaultOptions is Protected.

I dont know what that means, but execution proceeds correctly.

Should I turn that annoying message with `Off` in an initialization cell?

Comment: Have you tried contacting WRI Support? Without further details only those who have faced it could help you here.

Comment: Are you able to share this Notebook?  The cause is probably apparent from its content.